# Android onCreateAnimation Lifecycle

Tags: android, android-support-library

I've updated the support library from 24.2.1 to 26.0.0 and i noticed a difference which i'm not sure if its a bug or a clear decision to change.

I use fragments with custom animations for the transitions, and on the old 24.2.1 the lifecycle was like this

```
onAttach()
onCreate()
onCreateView()
onCreateAnimation()
onStart()
onResume()
```

but on the 26.0.0 it changed to

```
onAttach()
onCreate()
onCreateView()
onStart()
onResume()
onCreateAnimation()
```

For some reason not known to me, and looking through the support library release notes i haven't found nothing that could be related to this. The only thing that could be related was the re-order of the fragments, but event set that flag to true or false , did not have any effect.

Now my animations are a bit cranky because onResume() was expecting some flags to be set on onAnimationCreated() to behave accordingly.

Glad for the help,

Comment: created a github project to demonstrate this issue
https://github.com/smlima/createanim/

Comment: created a bug report sometime back, still waiting for them to reply

Answer (score 0):

According to Android Documentation about [`Fragment`](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html),

```
 onCreateAnimation(int transit, boolean enter, int nextAnim)
```

doesn't come under life cycle state of `Fragment`. It's just a normal method from the class `Fragment` which is called when a fragment loads an animation. 
See [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#onCreateAnimation(int,%20boolean,%20int)) too about `onCreateAnimation`. It says

> `Animation onCreateAnimation (int transit, boolean enter, int nextAnim)`
>   Called when a fragment loads an animation. Note that if setCustomAnimations(int, int) was called with Animator resources instead of Animation resources, nextAnim will be an animator resource.

I believe, this means the method gets called when you set Custom Animations to your fragment which can be before `onStart` method is triggred i.e. before the fragment is visible or after it.

Comment: I know that method it's not part of the lifecycle, but it's as it was, because that method was always called on that sequence, and now it changed. And it kinda make sense to be called before onResume(). Just found this discrepancy and wanted to make sure it's not a bug or anything like that. Now i will update my code to be independent of that method somehow ...
Thanks

Comment: Why always transit and nextAnim parameters are zero even using setCustomAnimations!